# Overlapping instances for `Compose` with `Contravariant` and `Functor`

Tags: haskell, typeclass

While solving the last exercise of [this course](https://github.com/system-f/fp-course/blob/master/src/Course/Compose.hs), I realized that not only we can have

```hs
instance (Functor f, Contravariant g) => Contravariant (Compose f g) where
-- Implement the (>$<) function for a Contravariant instance for Compose
  (>$<) :: (b -> a) -> Compose f g a -> Compose f g b
  fun >$< Compose fga = Compose ((fun >$<) <$> fga)
```

but also

```hs
instance (Contravariant f, Functor g) => Contravariant (Compose f g) where
-- Implement the (>$<) function for a Contravariant instance for Compose
  (>$<) :: (b -> a) -> Compose f g a -> Compose f g b
  fun >$< Compose fga = Compose ((fun <$>) >$< fga)
```

The problem is that I cannot get the module to compile when I put both definitions. The error I get is

```
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance (Functor f, Contravariant g) =>
               Contravariant (Compose f g)
        -- Defined at /.../fp-course/src/Course/Compose.hs:62:10
      instance (Contravariant f, Functor g) =>
               Contravariant (Compose f g)
        -- Defined at /.../fp-course/src/Course/Compose.hs:71:10
   |
62 | instance (Functor f, Contravariant g) =>
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

and I couldn't manage to get rid of it by adding the deprecated extension `{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}` or the `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}`/`{-# OVERLAPPING #-}`/`{-# OVERLAPS #-}` pragmas as explained [here](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/instances.html#overlapping-instances).

Is there a way to have both definitions in the module?

---

*Edit:* sorry I forgot to mention that the course redefines custom type classes `Functor`, `Contravariant`, etc... `(>$<)` corresponds to [`contramap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#v:contramap).

Comment: I don't think this is possible to achieve as stated. At best, we could write a custom class `WhichFunctor` that "tells" whether `f` is covariant or contravariant, and then exploit that to write the above instances. However, this approach would require to manually tag each functor with its own form ("co" or "contra"). Without that... we can't really react to the failure of a constraint, so we can't say "try covariant first, if that fails try contravariant" -- overlapping only cares about instance heads, not their contexts.

Comment: For a concrete example of where the ambiguity would arise, `Const a` (for any type `a`) is both a covariant and a contravariant functor. So which of the two instances you proposed should `Compose (Const a) (Const a)` take?

Comment: I'm very puzzled by this. So basically we should ditch `Compose` and define a plethora of wrappers `FunctorContravariant`, `ContravariantFunctor`, `ApplicativeMonad`, `ContravariantApplicative`, etc., and implement the appropriate type classes for each of them?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I don't have a general answer. Either let the programmer make sure that the possible alternatives are equivalent (in the same way as it's the programmer responsibility to make sure that the functorial/applicative/monadic laws are upheld), or have a way to specify which takes precedence.

Comment: In my experience, I seldom use `Compose` outside of clever mathematical proofs that aren't meant as production programs. And on the rare occasions when I *do* use `Compose`, I'm almost always using it with two covariant functors anyway. The number of use cases in real-world software for "I need the composition of two functors of opposite variance, and I'd like to use it in a contravariant way, and there's no `newtype` name I can use to make this abomination more readable" is, in my mind, vanishingly small.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The question isn't really about `Compose`. It is just an example that spontaneously came up but is much more general. The general problem would be "implement the class `C` for the type `T a1 a2 a3 ...` whenever the parameters `a1`, `a2`, ..., implement some classes".

Comment: Ok I just found that what I suggested in the previous comment actually exists. In [`Data.Functor.Contravariant.Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.5.5/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Compose.html) there are `ComposeFC` and `ComposeCF`. This is such a disgrace...

Comment: For what it's worth, the idea you're proposing (allowing multiple instances with matching heads for the same typeclass) has been explored in some other languages. Notably, Scala will allow any number of implicits for the same type, but if it's ambiguous then it's your job as the programmer to specify which one you want. It... mostly works, but it breaks coherence. For instance, if I use one `Ord` instance to insert something into a map and then another to query the map, then the orderings won't match up and things won't go well.

Comment: Scalaz is one of Scala's prominent libraries for adding typeclass-style programming (and monads) from Haskell into Scala, and it basically un-implements the feature you're proposing and re-implements Haskell's newtype solution via tagged types, to get back coherence.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yes I realize this may open up the doors to some hard-to-spot bugs, but then does it mean we are left with `ComposeFC`, `ComposeCF`, etc...? I'm probably not too accustomed to thinking in the same way as Haskell classes work, but to me it seems that the usefulness of `Compose` is severely hindered if we cannot implement its "functorialness" in more than one case. Is there a nicer pattern to avoid the proliferation of newtypes `ComposeFC`, `ComposeCF`, etc.?

Comment: This isn't a problem if we [unified `Functor` and `Contravariant`](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/eoo16m/base_category_polymorphic_functor_and_functorof/)

Comment: @Iceland_jack good point, but there are new problems. A `Functor` class can perfectly well be designed to allow different categories, [e.g. the `constrained-categories` one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Functor-Constrained.html#t:Functor). However if you allow functors to map between multiple different categories (as with `Const` that can map to either **Hask** or Op(**Hask**)) then type inference becomes very awkward, you'll certainly need many more annotations; that's why `constrained-categories` prohibits this with a fundep.

Comment: That's right although `Const` can be parameterised on its categories there are many issues with overlapping behaviour. Every function `f` can be seen as a maximally uninteresting, maximally overlapping `FunctorOf (:~:) (:~:) f` instance. That cannot be captured completely with a `newtype`. There are other design considerations but I don't actually think inference is important for `Functor`. I think pockets of nice inference can be bolted on to it depending on how it is used in practice. The design space is admittedly vast compared to the current Haskell class hierarchy.

Comment: I had the fear that this conversation would turn into a jumble-mumble of "cocontravariant universally homomorphizing cofunctorial monoidal categories etc.". The example I gave involves `Functor`, `Contravariant` and `Compose` only for showcase purposes, but the issue is more general and has nothing to do with `Functor` itself. The type `Compose` has two parameters and can behave as a `Functor` for different combinations of the parameters. Is there a way to encode this or are forced to duplicate code by creating `Compose1`, `Compose2`, etc.? That doesn't look like a very powerful design choice.

Comment: The "generality" of `Compose` is severely diminished if we have to give it a different name for every combination of parameters. Basically it would mean that we cannot capture the concept of composition in the Haskell type-system. If I have to treat separately all possible combinations of type classes, then it's pretty analogous to not having type classes at all.

Comment: The way to encode it is a `newtype`

Comment: @Federico The answer to the general question was already given by Silvio Mayolo above. What you want is fundamentally incompatible with instance coherence. Instance coherence meaning that there is at most one unique instance for any type class and type combination. This is a well-known problem for which no solution exists. That's why the discussion shifted to the only currently possible solution of your question: How could one change the class hierachy to improve behaviour in this specific case.